# storing the original index after sorting using qsort

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, qsort

Suppose I have the following array:

```
int A[5]={2,3,5,4,1};
```

In this array, each of the index represents a player. For example:

```
A[0]=player 0
A[1]=player 1
.....
```

I want to sort the array in descending order like this:

```
A[5]={5,4,3,2,1};
```

and also I want to trace the previous index of the players so that I can write the sorted array like this:

```
{player 2, player 4, player 1, player 0,player 4}
```

In a word, I want to trace the original index. I have written a program in C using qsort to arrange the elements in descending order.

```
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <stdlib.h>     

int A[] = {2,3,5,4,1};

int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
   return ( *(int*)b - *(int*)a );
}

int main ()
{
  int n;
  qsort (A, 5, sizeof(int), compare);
  for (n=0; n<5; n++)
  printf ("%d ",A[n]);
  return 0;
}
```

Is is possible to trace the original index also using this qsort?

Comment: Note that `b - a` sorts in descending order.

Comment: yes. I want descending order @Maxim Egorushkin

Answer (score 4):

It is a common requirement. A possible way is to replace the array of ints with and array of 2 element structures:

```
struct PlayerScore {
    int playerId;
    int score;
}
```

Your code could become:

```
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <stdlib.h>     

int A[] = {2,3,5,4,1};
#define N sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0])

struct PlayerScore {
    int playerId;
    int score;
};
int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
    return ( (*(struct PlayerScore*)b).score - (*(struct PlayerScore*)a).score );
}

int main ()
{
  int n;
  struct PlayerScore ps[N];
  for(n=0;n<N; n++) {
      ps[n].playerId = n;
      ps[n].score = A[n];
  }
  qsort (ps, 5, sizeof(struct PlayerScore), compare);
  for (n=0; n<N; n++)
      printf ("%d (%d) ",ps[n].score, ps[n].playerId);
  return 0;
}
```

And you finally get:

```
5 (2) 4 (3) 3 (1) 2 (0) 1 (4)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem has nothing to do with qsort as such, but merely program design.

"In this array, each of the index represents a player" is the problem. You have invented a weird dependency between the array indexes and the contents, even though you want to change the array indexes.

Instead of arrays of int, filled with cryptic "magic numbers", make an array of structs with meaningful data.

It could for example be something like this:

```
typedef struct
{
  // whatever makes sense to store here, names, stats etc      
} player_t;

player_t players [] = 
{
  {0, ...},
  {1, ...},
};
```

Now you can qsort that table based on whatever you like.

Please note that for performance reasons, it might be better to declare an array of pointers-to-struct and then qsort that array. Far less data shuffling for qsort that way.

Comment: You are not answering the question.

Comment: @vz0 I am, I'm pointing out that this should be re-designed entirely. I would not do the OP a favour by pretending that their problem makes sense and lead them astray to complete obfuscation, by inventing some mess of magic numbers. This is essentially the same answer as posted as Serge, though he was perhaps a bit more pedagogic with his nice example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort pairs of numbers, for example by storing each piece of information in a struct:

```
struct player {
  int data;
  int index;
};

struct player A[] = {{2,0}, {3,1}, {5,2}, {4,3}, {1,4}};

int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
   return ( ((struct player*)b)->data - ((struct player*)a)->data );
}

int main ()
{
  int n;
  qsort (A, 5, sizeof(struct player), compare);
  for (n=0; n<5; n++)
  printf ("data=%d, index=%d\n", A[n].data, A[n].index);
  return 0;
}
```